# Laravel Seeding Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I'm having an issue regarding Laravel's Seeding... so I'm getting a `[ErrorException] Illegal offset type` from One of My seeds. I believe my issue is coming from the foreign key, from the other table that I'm using

Below is My Model, My Table and My Seed which I'm getting.

Channel - Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Tenant;
use App\InactiveLead;
use App\Lead;


class Channel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $primaryKey = ['channel_id'];

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'tenant_name'];

    public function tenant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tenant::class, 'name', 'tenant_name');
    }

    public function inactivelead()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InactiveLead::class, 'inactive_lead_id', 'inactive_lead_id');
    }

    public function lead()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Lead::class, 'lead_id', 'lead_id');
    }
}
```

Channel - Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateChannelsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('channels', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('channel_id');

            $table->string('name');

            $table->string('tenant_name');
            $table->foreign('tenant_name')->references('name')->on('tenants');

            $table->unique(['tenant_name', 'name']);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('channels');
    }
}
```

Channel - Seeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Tenant;
use App\Channel;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class ChannelsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
    $faker = Faker::create();

    $Tenants = Tenant::all()->pluck('name')->toArray();

    $Channels = array('SMS', 'Email', 'MMS', 'Call');

    $limit = 100;

    for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        $channel = new Channel([
            'tenant_name' => $faker->unique()->randomElement($Tenants),
            'name' => $faker->unique()->randomElement($Channels)
        ]);

        $channel->save();
    }
}
}
```

Below is my Logs:

```
[2017-06-29 08:49:11] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Illegal offset type in C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php:818
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(818): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Illegal offset ...', 'C:\\Users\\Myster...', 818, Array)
#1 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(803): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getCasts()
#2 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(832): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->hasCast('tenant_name', Array)
#3 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(565): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->isDateCastable('tenant_name')
#4 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(525): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->isDateAttribute('tenant_name')
#5 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(230): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->setAttribute('tenant_name', 'sunt')
#6 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(152): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fill(Array)
#7 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\database\seeds\ChannelsTableSeeder.php(29): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__construct(Array)
#8 [internal function]: ChannelsTableSeeder->run()
#9 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#11 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#12 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#13 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Seeder.php(114): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#14 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Seeder.php(37): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->__invoke()
#15 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php(22): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->call('ChannelsTableSe...')
#16 [internal function]: DatabaseSeeder->run()
#17 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#19 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#20 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#21 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Seeder.php(114): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#22 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php(63): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->__invoke()
#23 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes.php(122): Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\{closure}()
#24 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php(64): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguarded(Object(Closure))
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->fire()
#26 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#28 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#29 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#30 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#31 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(264): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#32 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#33 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(869): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(223): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(130): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 C:\Users\Mystere\seoforge_v5\artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#38 {main}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that, in your Seeder, pluck() already makes an array of the collection. You should remove the ->toArray(). Didn't test it, though.

Comment: Calling `pluck()` on a collection will return an array, so you shouldn't call `toArray()` on that, but that shouldn't raise an offset exception. Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for more info on the exception.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using exactly?

Comment: I could be wrong but at a quick glance you're using `unique()` for `name` in your `Channel` class and you're creating 100 channels but you only have 4 `$Channels` to choose from. Also, do you have 100+ unique tenant names to choose from?

Comment: @thomas_inckx I'll test that out...

Comment: @Robert I'll adjust my Question to include my Log...

Comment: @lesssugar I'm using 5.4

Comment: @RossWilson I'm actually considering that.... Because the Constraints for my Channel Table are that they both have to be unique....which might be firing the error.

Comment: your constraint on the table is for a unique combination of channel_name and name, but Ross might be right as well as faker unique() will only pick the items once. But according to the faker docs that should throw an OverflowException.

Comment: I've just had a look at the `UniqueGenerator` class and @Robert is right, it will throw an `OverflowException`. I would still suggest removing the `unique()` method from the `name` though as it should be unique anyway as you're using it on the `tenant_name`. I would also suggest changing the logic for `$limit` to something like `$limit = count($Tenants) < 100 ? count($Tenants) : 100;` (unless you're definitely going to have 100+ tenants in your DB already).

Comment: @thomas_inckx ... I tried removing the -<toArray(), but that causes an error on the RandomElement for Faker since pluck returns an Object and not an Array.

Comment: @RossWilson I'll give that a go, that's actually a good Idea... I also removed the Unique Constraint on the name, just to have Tenant as the Unique Constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is because you have defined your `$primaryKey` as an array.

Change it from:

```
protected $primaryKey = ['channel_id'];
```

To:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'channel_id';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @GregSithole Glad I could help! :)